# Using and running Tortoise svnsync in Windows via command line

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, svnsync

I have a local repository and I have just signed up to `unfuddle` and want to sync my local repository to the new one I have created on there.

I was told to run the following command:

```
svnsync init --username USERNAME http://username.unfuddle.com/svn/username-rep http://SOURCE_REPO_URL
```

Firstly, I assume I can remove the username stuff if the source repository doesn't require authentication?

Secondly, when I run that command my system doesn't recognize it. I assumed `svnsync` needed to be added somewhere in Windows so that it could be run via it's name only (think the correct term is an `environment variable`)?, but not only do I not know how to do that I don't know what program to add...... I cannot find any `svnsync.exe` or anything locate din my `TortoiseSVN` folder.

What do I need to do here?

Comment: Well if the creator of TortoiseSVN can't help me then I don't think I have much chance of others helping me either lol.... also not sure why my tag for `tortoisesvn` was removed when I was asking why I don't have the `svsnync` program included in the download I got?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you install TortoiseSVN you are given the option to install the Subversion binaries as well:

[image: TortoiseSVN custom installation]

Once you do that, you will see `svnsync.exe` in the installation folder:

[image: Location of the SVN binaries installed by TortoiseSVN]

As long as you have `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin` in your `PATH` variable, you will be able to call `svnsync.exe` from the command-line:

[image: TortoiseSVN in PATH variable]

(You can view your PATH variable thus (on Windows 7): **Start** `->` ***right-click* Computer** `->` **Properties** `->` **Advanced system settings** `->` **Environment variables...**. **DO NOT** overwrite whatever is there - simply append the path to TortoiseSVN if it isn't already there. [More info here](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx).)

[image: svnsync working from the C:\ path in the command-line]

Hope this helps.